# OneDrive Office 365 - Power Query

Tags: office365, powerbi, onedrive

I use Power Query extensively to pull data from files in folders, stored on drives. My company is moving away from shared drives in favour of storing documents on OneDrive as part of their Office 365 package.

This will clearly wreck the M-Coded filepaths in my queries. But, how does Power Query interact with Office 365/OneDrive?

Is it even possible to recreate what I was doing if all my source files have been moved to this location?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem you can change the source step of edit queries from local excel file to onedrive. I have a post in my blog on how to get this data, but I have to warn is in spanish.
https://blog.ladataweb.com.ar/post/185337134590/alternativa-para-conectar-power-bi-a-onedrive

Hope it helps,
Regards